# How to trigger event on windows load

Tags: javascript, jquery

i like to execute `$('select[name="order_id"]').change()` on windows load but is not doing anything

if i debug this is browser console i can see script is execute `$('select[name="order_id"]').change()` but nothing happen is not sending ajax request

if i manually change the select or paste in browser console `$('select[name="order_id"]').change()` everything work fine

any ideas how to fix it ? i also tried with `.trigger('change')` but is same issue

```
        window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
      
      <?php if ($logged): ?>
      
      $('select[name="order_id"]').change()
      
      $('select[name="order_id"]').change(function(){
        var order_id = $(this).val();
        isSelectedOrder = true

        $.ajax({
              url: 'index.php?route=return/getProductsByOrderId',
              data: {order_id:order_id},
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              beforeSend: function(){

                .......
                .....
                ..
                .

        <?php endif; ?> 
        
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you trigger the `change()` before attaching the event, all you need to do is move the trigger of the `change()` to after you attach the event.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
      <? php if ($logged): ?>
      
      $('select[name="order_id"]').on('change', function () {
            var order_id = $(this).val();
            isSelectedOrder = true

            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=return/getProductsByOrderId',
                data: { order_id: order_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {

                .......
                },
            });
        });

        $('select[name="order_id"]').change()

    <? php endif; ?> 
});
```

Comment: so stupid but is work :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code block

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

ref: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: still same issue not working